# Keep process running after close session

Tags: raspbian

I launch below process with `&` so as to keep it running in background after I close session :

```
pi@raspberrypi2 ~ $ ./spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker -m 700M spark://192.168.192.22:7077 &
[1] 3538
pi@raspberrypi2 ~ $ Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/04/04 19:35:47 INFO Worker: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/04/04 19:35:47 WARN Utils: Your hostname, raspberrypi2 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.192.55 instead (on interface eth0)
15/04/04 19:35:47 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
^C
pi@raspberrypi2 ~ $ 15/04/04 19:35:51 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

But as can see, the output is just temporarily hidden from view and when I close session the process stops.

How to launch process on Raspbian and keep it running after I have closed PI session ?

I have tried installing screen but I'm unable to switch screens when content is logged to output ?

Comment: Look at the nohup command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a Linux general question as opposed to Pi specific ... but the answer is to use the `nohup` command.  Read about it here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Basically run:

```
$ nohup <your command and parameters go here> &
```

Nohup traps the `hangup` signal which is sent when you disconnect your screen/terminal from the process.

Comment: It is a general linux Q but if someone here has a decent quick answer, cool (+1).  I'd recommend `setsid` over `nohup` but if the latter works don't worry.

Comment: `tmux` is another option.

Comment: I prefer `nohup` as it's with raspbian by default, `tmux` isn't installed

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you are unable to switch screens? Usually you start `screen`, run the program, disconnect with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> then close `ssh`. Then open `ssh` later and check on the program with `screen -r` or `screen -ls` if more than one is running.