# launch OmxPlayer from ssh in loop, will close when ssh disconnect

Tags: ssh, omxplayer

I'm quite new to raspberry, all I need to do is to play a video in loop  from a local ssh connection. These are my step:

1. start the Pi in Cli (so no x server but command line) with network
2. open my windows terminal connect via ssh and launch the command `omxplayer --loop myfile.mp4`
3. Let the video plays it's eternal loop close the terminal and go home.

Now, the first two step are working correctly, what I expect is that the video continues to run even if I close the connection.

Where is my mistake? Is it possible to let it plays?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Bacground processes are still tied to the shell and are closed when the shell closes. Actually, `disown` wound't work either, unless omxplayer doesn't need a terminal to run and ignores "SIGHUP".

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev thanks for catching that I couldn't remember if that was the case or not, and was too tired/lazy to test it.

Comment: Does it work if you run `nohup omxplayer --loop myfile.mp4`?

Comment: Yes you must add sudo

Answer (score 1):

All commands you run via SSH are attached to the virtual SSH terminal and automatically closed when you disconnect. If you want a process to persist across sessions, you need to use `nohup`, `tmux`, `screen` or a similar command which either creates a persistent virtual terminal of replaces it with a file.

See [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29348/33476) for details and examples.